# Detect VMware product name from linux guest

Tags: vmware

Is this possible to detect VMware product name (ESXi, Workstation, Fusion, Player) from Linux guest?

I tried `libvirt-what` but it shows `vmware` on all platforms.

Any other ideas?

Comment: No you cannot. You can run a process externally to set the guest info through the API  and then query the guest info from inside the guest using VMware tools similar to this http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2011/01/how-to-extract-host-information-from.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command line tool available (with source code!) that uses the VMware "backdoor" I/O ports and can detect the hypervisor product. See [link](https://sites.google.com/site/chitchatvmback/vmtools#vmw).

The "Get VMware Version" command has the number 0ah, see [link](https://sites.google.com/site/chitchatvmback/backdoor#cmd0ah).

Comment: This seems to be very promising but I can't verify this. I mark this answer as accepted. If anyone verifies this please add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about ESXi, but QEMU you can detect this way - same might work for ESXi

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i qemu
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.0
```

Or

lspci -nn

might also help as you can look for certain devices that ESXi is emulating if you are using the ESXI specific para-virt network drivers.

Or you could try virt-what which seems comprehensive:

http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/

Or dmesg and then grep for fusion or esxi ?

Or sudo dmidecode | egrep -i 'manufacturer|product|vendor'

might help.

Low level wise, ESXI seems to use the 0x5658 io port. If you can craft a program to read from that you can get back 0x564D5868 (or 'VMXh').

Hopefully tho one of the above will help you. Please let me know, I'd be interested to know which works

Comment: Thanks for answer. I haven't tried IO port reading. But all other methods returns information that this is VMware without specifying which exactly product is used.

I gave +1 because you give many useful ways to check hypervisor from guest and reading IO port may be an answer I can't verify now.